# When dealing with session level data in a web app, is it better to maintain a static store of that data, or pass it around as needed?

Tags: object-oriented, web-development, asp.net, session, data-access

I have a web app that is capable of connecting to multiple databases that are identical in structure but contain different data; each of our clients who uses the app gets their own copy of the database to avoid commingling of different clients' data. We determine which database to connect to by looking up the client's ID in a master database.

That sounds like a pretty solid design - however I have a question about what we should do with the connection strings once we retrieve them. Right now most of the data access functions look something like this:

```
Public Function GetUsersByRole(ByVal roleID As Integer, ByVal connectionString As String) As SqlDataReader
    ' connect to database using connection string passed in
    ' execute query
    ' return results
End Function
```

And we call it like so:

```
Dim connstr = Session("DotNetConnectionString") ' this session variable is populated from the master database when you log in
Dim drAdmins As SqlDataReader = DBFunctions.GetUsersByRole(1, connstr)
```

However I think it would be cleaner to instead have a central location to retrieve the connection string, so we don't have to keep retrieving it over and over again and passing it in every time we want to do a query:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property ConnectionString As String
    Get
        Return Session("DotNetConnectionString")
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetUsersByRole(ByVal roleID As Integer) As SqlDataReader
    ' connect to database using connection string from shared property defined above
    ' execute query
    ' return results
End Function
```

Then all you have to do to call it is:

```
Dim drAdmins As SqlDataReader = DBFunctions.GetUsersByRole(1)
```

So much easier!

Does my approach make sense or should I leave things as is? (In general, I'm not changing the existing data access methods; I'm mostly just doing it this way when I create new ones. There are too many data access functions for changing them all to be worthwhile!) I can see one potential disadvantage: it's now impossible to query any client database other than the current client's database. But really, why would you want to?! That sounds like a really bad idea, or a huge mistake waiting to happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever need to call `GetUsersByRole` with varying connection strings?  If not, then the parameterization offers no value, and you might as well omit the parameter.

If you use the static function from multiple other functions, then it is worth defining as such instead of repeating `Session("DotNetConnectionString")` within those other functions, mostly to remove the magic string from more of the code.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we do any cross-system calls, apart from the login screen where we need to determine which system to connect the user to (if they belong to only one system, we connect to that automatically, but if they belong to multiple, they can choose). And the latter case is really only used in development and testing; there aren't any end users that I know of who actually belong to more than one client agency! So I think it's safe to say that we never need to call these functions with varying connection strings. Thanks!